# SoundManager2 creating and playing 55 sounds

Tags: javascript, audio, soundmanager2

UPDATE: so I found this on Adobe's AS3 spec:

> SoundChannel — A SoundChannel object, which you use to control the sound. This method returns null if you have no sound card or if you run out of available sound channels. The maximum number of sound channels available at once is 32.

source: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html

Example code: http://charliehield.com/sandbox/sm2/

I'm creating the 55 sounds with the following function:

```
function makeSomeNoize(){
        for(var i = 1; i <= 55; i++){
            var SoundObject = soundManager.createSound({
                stream: false,
                id: 'sound'+i+'',
                url:'clips/mp3/sound'+i+'.mp3',
                autoPlay: false,
                multiShot: false,
                loops: 9999,
                volume: 30 
            }).load();
        }
    }
```

Next, I trigger playing the clips and muting them with a click function on the start button.

```
$('#start').click(function (){

            $(this).fadeOut('slow');

            for(var i = 1; i <= 55; i++){
                soundManager.play('sound'+i);
                soundManager.mute('sound'+i);
            }
        });
```

And then each button uses the toggleMute(); function (so that the sounds are looping "in sync" and then you can just toggle their volume).

Only issue is that I can see the 55 sonds being loaded, but only the first 32 sound will actually play.

I'm totally stuped. Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried coping `clips/mp3/sound1.mp3` as `sound33.mp3` in case the format or maybe the file is invalid? Just a thought

Comment: Maybe SoundManager is limited to 32 sounds?

Comment: Hmmm well in earlier stages I checked the i variable, which correctly incremented 1,2,3...54,55 which is what all the sounds are named.

Comment: It's just weird why it would only play 32 sounds. 32 is power of 2^5.